# Edit access - 2 profiles

Tags: profile, sharing-rule, access

I have 2 profiles A and B. Both have same access on Account object and have same permission sets. profile A cannot edit the account but profile B can. What could be causing this? anything I am missing which gives extra access to profile B. I want to restrict editing of account.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you let me know if any of the answers works for you. Till today you have not accepted any answers of your questions. Are you not getting proper answers?

Answer (score 0):

This is may be due to record level access. You didn't mention who is owner of the account and how the account record is shared to the user.

You can specify validation rule to restrict the editing of records.

Answer (score 0):

In order to restrict editing the records, you can use sharing setting to make the record as Read-only for specific users / roles/ groups.

Also check if there is any Apex sharing via code on account for edit permissions.